# AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'fetchall'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, attributeerror

What am I doing wrong here?

```
engine_str = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://my_username:my_pass@localhost/my_db'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_str, echo=False, encoding='utf-8')
connection = engine.connect()
query = "SELECT * from history_table"

connection.execute(query)
rows = connection.fetchall()
```

### Error

```
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'fetchall'
```

Answer (score 3):

`fetchall` is a method of a cursor, not a connection.

```
query = "SELECT * from history_table"
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

I have no idea why you've brought sqlalchemy into this though. You are not using it at all; you are just going straight to the underlying database API.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'cursor'`

I am using sqlalchemy to connect to my database.

Comment: Then why are you trying to use `fetchall`? That's a method of the db api, not of sqlalchemy. As [the sqlalchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html) show, to get results from that you just iterate over the return value of `execute`.

Answer (score 0):

```
engine_str = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://my_username:my_pass@localhost/my_db'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_str, echo=False, encoding='utf-8')
connection = engine.connect()
query = "SELECT * from history_table"

rows = connection.execute(query) 
# cursor will save records later we can fetch but in sqlalchemy 
# have to save the results while executing 

result = rows.fetchall()
```